# grails: guidance on writing scripts, esp for calling existing database-migration scripts

Tags: grails, scripting, database-migration

My requirement is to invoke some processing from a Jenkins build server, to determine whether the domain model has changed since the last build. I've come to the conclusion that the way forward is to write a script that will invoke a sequence of existing scripts from the db-migration plugin. Then I can invoke it in the step that calls test-app and war.

I've looked in the Grails doc, and at some of the db-migration scripts, and I find I'm stuck - have no idea where to start trying things. I'd be really grateful if someone could point me at any suitable sources. BTW, I'm a bit rusty in Grails. Started to teach myself two years ago via proof of concept project, which lasted 6 months. Then it was back to Eclipse rich client work. That might be part of my problem, though I never go involved in scripts.

One thing I need in the Jenkins evt is to get hold of the current SVN revision number being used for the build. Suggestions welcome.

Regards, John

Answer (score 1):

Create a new script by running `grails create-script scriptname`. The database-migration plugins scripts are configured to be easily reused. There are is a lot of shared code in `_DatabaseMigrationCommon.groovy` and each script defines one target with a unique name. So you can import either the shared script or any standalone script (or multiple scripts) and call the targets like they're methods.

By default the script generated by `create-script` "imports" the `_GrailsInit` script via `includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")` and you can do the same, taking advantage of the magic variables that point at installed plugins' directories:

```
includeTargets << new File("$databaseMigrationPluginDir/scripts/DbmGenerateChangelog.groovy")
```

If you do this you can remove the include of _GrailsInit since it's already included, but if you don't that's fine since Grails only includes files once.

Then you can define your target and call any of the plugin's targets. The targets cannot accept parameters, but you can add data to the `argsMap` (this is a map Grails creates from the parsed commandline arguments) to simulate user-specified args. Note that any args passed to your script will be seen by the database-migration plugin's scripts since they use the same `argsMap`.

Here's an example script that just does the same thing as `dbm-generate-changelog` but adds a before and after message:

```
includeTargets << new File("$databaseMigrationPluginDir/scripts/DbmGenerateChangelog.groovy")

target(foo: "Just calls dbmGenerateChangelog") {
   println 'before'
   dbmGenerateChangelog()
   println 'after'
}

setDefaultTarget foo
```

Note that I renamed the target from `main` to `foo` so it's unique, in case you want to call this from another script.

As an example of working with args, here's a modified version that specifies a default changelog name if none is provided:

```
println 'before'
if (!argsMap.params) {
   argsMap.params = ['foo2.groovy']
}
dbmGenerateChangelog()
println 'after'
```

**Edit**: Here's a fuller example that captures the output of dbm-gorm-diff to a string:

```
includeTargets << new File("$databaseMigrationPluginDir/scripts/_DatabaseMigrationCommon.groovy")

target(foo: "foo") {
   depends dbmInit

   def configuredSchema = config.grails.plugin.databasemigration.schema
   String argSchema = argsMap.schema
   String effectiveSchema = argSchema ?: configuredSchema ?: defaultSchema

   def realDatabase
   boolean add = false // booleanArg('add')
   String filename = null // argsList[0]

   try {
      printMessage "Starting $hyphenatedScriptName"

      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
      def baosOut = new PrintStream(baos)

      ScriptUtils.executeAndWrite filename, add, dsName, { PrintStream out ->
         MigrationUtils.executeInSession(dsName) {
            realDatabase = MigrationUtils.getDatabase(effectiveSchema, dsName)
            def gormDatabase = ScriptUtils.createGormDatabase(dataSourceSuffix, config, appCtx, realDatabase, effectiveSchema)
            ScriptUtils.createAndPrintFixedDiff(gormDatabase, realDatabase, realDatabase, appCtx, diffTypes, baosOut)
         }
      }

      String xml = new String(baos.toString('UTF-8'))
      def ChangelogXml2Groovy = classLoader.loadClass('grails.plugin.databasemigration.ChangelogXml2Groovy')
      String groovy = ChangelogXml2Groovy.convert(xml)

      // do something with the groovy or xml here

      printMessage "Finished $hyphenatedScriptName"
   }
   catch (e) {
      ScriptUtils.printStackTrace e
      exit 1
   }
   finally {
      ScriptUtils.closeConnection realDatabase
   }
}

setDefaultTarget foo
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's really good of you to take the trouble to provide me with such a helpful starter. I've managed to create a 'diff' file now. If I don't provide a file name parm to dbmGormDiff(), the output is seen in the console (as specified). 
Is it possible to get the console output directed into a closure in my script? That way I could search for '<changeSet' to determine if the domain model has been changed. (If found, I then know to re-run with a filename+svn-revno and --add). I feel I'm now making progress.

Comment: Thanks Burt - a really great help. As I'm still using 1.2.2, I based my code in substituting 'boasOut' in a copy of that version of DbmGormDiff. I created an internal 'utils' script for use by my main script. Most is now working. If there are domain changes, and if the changelog-svnRevno.xml file exists (= rerunning), I delete it and proceed. 
My one problem is how to stop the master.xml from being updated with duplicate 'includes'. Not sure I can solve that by getting earlier version from SVN, because I don't know how may reruns there have been. Think I'm getting the hang of simple scripting.

Comment: This is going beyond the scope of a SO question - you might want to discuss this on the User mailing list.

Comment: Understand your point. Really grateful for the help you have given.
John